# Правильно ли говорить: "Журнал регистрации и учёта"?

Tags: выбор-слов, смысл, плеоназм, речевая-избыточность

По-моему — нет: регистрация и учёт в делопроизводстве — одно и то же.

Answer (score 2):

> ... регистрация и учёт в делопроизводстве - одно и то же.

Вовсе не обязательно. Простой пример. Для журнала регистрации посетителей вполне достаточно будет регистрировать только имя посетителя и время входа. А для учёта необходимо отслеживать также время убытия.

В общем случае регистрация чего-либо в делопроизводстве относится к какому-то конкретному событию (возможно, нескольким), а учёт — это регистрация всех событий, подлежащих учёту и позволяющих получить требуемую информацию в определённый момент времени.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что не совсем правильно. Но не по причине якобы тавтологии, а потому как нужно какое-то содержательное слово, раскрывающее, что именно там учитывают и регистрируют. Иначе как-то бессмысленно получается.
А уже в зависимости от этого дополнения можно ставить вопрос об избыточности формулировки.

*"Журнал регистрации и учета сильнодействующих наркосодержащих препаратов"*, к примеру, не выглядит плеоназмом (пример условный, в реальности он носит другое название), поскольку "учет" и "регистрация" в этом случает - вещи разные, "учет" понятие более емкое.

Ну или, предположим, *"учет и регистрация окольцованных перелетных птиц"*. Тут регистрация - это, наоборот, более полное, как в паспортном столе: нечто персонифицирующее экземпляр объекта учета. А если, продолжая орнитологическую тему, это *учет времени, потраченного на подсчет пролетающих мимо окна ворон*, то тут трудно действительно придумать, зачем их вообще регистрировать и чем оная регистрация отличается от простого учета.

Впрочем, обычно названия подобных журналов закреплены в нормирующих документах. Составители же таких документов семантической логикой обычно не обременены, но с ними не поспоришь. Так что даже если очевидна несуразность названия, лучше не связываться.

Answer (score 1):

Название "журнал регистрации и учета"  входит в терминологию  делопроизводства.

Рассмотрим, к примеру, **журнал регистрации и учета трудовых договоров** и их движения на предприятии. https://econ.wikireading.ru/39072

При регистрации документу присваивается номер (это облегчит поиск документа). Трудовой договор в дальнейшем может быть изменен, также для данного работника учитываются переводы, отслеживаются отпуска, всё это можно отнести к кадровому  учету.

**Насколько правильно и логично такое название?**

**Регистрация** ― это запись, которая делается **с определенной целью.**

Из словаря:

**РЕГИСТРИРОВАТЬ,** нсв. (св. зарегистрировать). кого-что. Отмечать **с целью учёта**, систематизации, придания законной силы и т.п. Р. поступающую корреспонденцию. Р. делегатов конференции. Р. акты гражданского состояния.

**Полное название** выглядело бы так: журнал регистрации с целью учета, журнал регистрации и последующего учета.

В названии можно использовать только одно действие: **журнал регистрации или  журнал учета,** но это не меняет сути (эти функции всегда совмещены). Чтобы учесть, надо сначала зарегистрировать, а после регистрации остается только функция учета.

Из словаря:

**УЧЁТ,** 2. Контроль за наличием и использованием денежных средств, производственных и трудовых ресурсов, за производством и потреблением продуктов и товаров и т.п. Вести строгий у. продовольственных запасов города. Взять на у. земельные фонды. Народно-хозяйственный, статистический, бухгалтерский, оперативно-технический у.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже писали, регистрация и учёт в делопроизводстве — не одно и то же. Однако не вижу смысла соединять одно и другое в названии журнала. Обычо регистрация ведется для учета. Учет без регистрации невозможен. Если уж упоминать учет в названии, то *регистрация* — лишнее слово.

В Нацкорусе найдено 30 вхождений *журнала регистрации*, 69 вхождений *журнала учета* и только один(!) пример совмещения регистрации и учета, причем в обратном порядке (?!):

> Однако в машине имелся «**журнал учета и регистрации** правонарушений», в котором дисциплинированный ефрейтор сделал свою последнюю запись следующего содержания… [Максим Милованов. Естественный отбор (2000)]

Comment: Пример из подобной беллетристики - не самый удачный, этот журнал по-другому называется. А вот что делать, например, с этим?  http://www.centrmag.ru/catalog/product/zhurnal_registratsii_i_ucheta_silnykh_reaktsiy_na_privivki_i_postvaktsinalnykh_oslozhneniy_/

Comment: или вот http://www.hr-ok.ru/e-store/personnel_registration/7191/ эти формы - обе утверждены "высочайшими" инструкциями... и вот еще шедевр канцеляризма. https://magazinot.ru/zhurnal_registratsii_i_ucheta_ispytaniy_lestnits_pristavnyh_stremyanok_48_stranits_kod_zh100/?uid:000251412

Comment: По первой ссылке все остальные журналы - либо учета, либо регистрации, только один  и того и другого. Возможно,  чье-то упущение?

Comment: @Мимоходов По второй ссылке я не нашел, где сказано, что **форма журнала** утверждена кем-то.